# Realm ReactNative flexible sync based on Embedded field query data or OnetoMany relational field data

Tags: mongodb, react-native, realm

I have a collection say Product and It has 1 embedded field "store". store is an array of object with its inventory details. it contains 1 or more stores where a product is available.
I want to sync products based on "store_id" field for e.g. get all products where "store_id=1001". How can I do with realm flexible sync?. currently I tried to pass query in subscription of collection but it returns no data.

```
collection schema:
const ProductSchema = {
name: 'Product',
  properties: {
    _id: 'objectId',
    brand: 'string',
    categoryid: 'objectId',
    cost: 'double',
    date_created: 'string',
    date_updated: 'string',
    createdby: 'objectId',
    store: {type: 'list', objectType: 'EmbStores'},
    }
}

const EmbProdStoreSchema = {
  name: 'EmbStores',
  embedded: true,
  properties: {
    inventory: 'int?',
    isactive: 'bool?',
    price: 'double?',
    store_id: 'int?',
  },
};
```

Comment: At a high level, you can query on embedded objects through the (top level) parent object. The query would be on your product objects and the store.store_id property equals to "1001"

Comment: @Jay Thanks, My issue is query during sync subscription. your solution will work after syncing data into local db.

Comment: Not sure I understand that comment. The point of creating a `QuerySubscription` is to perform the query, regardless of status, which will return the results in the closure following the query - that holds true for both standard sync and flexible sync. Perhaps you can clarify the question with more details and some example code so we will understand what's being asked. See [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)